# Should I encrypt my backup HDDs?

Tags: backup, encryption

I want to encrypt the HDDs that I use for backups, but I am also afraid of encryption making my HDDs more prone to failures. Should I encrypt them anyways?

Comment: Yes. Just have an extra backup drive if you're concerned. They won't fail simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I encrypt them?

Yes, you should. Encrypting data on your main drive is pointless if you have unencrypted copies elsewhere. (Note that this also applies to cloud storage.)

> I am afraid of encryption making my HDDs more prone to failures.

Encryption doesn't affect failure rates. Drives don't care what kind of data you're putting on them, it's just a stream of bytes.

Comment: But wouldn't the corruption of some part of the HDD make it harder to recover just because of using encryption?

Comment: Yes, it probably will be harder to recover data if your encrypted drive fails. Say, if a special block where volume key is stored become unreadable, you are lost all the data, because although all other data blocks are readable, you won't be able to decrypt them. This is the price you pay for security. Have more backups if you are concerned. It is not that hard, for instance, for encfs encryption, you have only to second-backup "superblock" .encfs6.xml file.

Comment: I guess in Veracrypt you can backup the volume key burning the Veracrypt Rescue Disk, right?

Comment: If you have to recover your backup then you're doing it wrong. Follow the 3-2-1 rule: 3 copies on 2 kinds of media, including 1 in remote location.

Comment: And don't forget the other rule: Test that you can restore from the backups ...